# Numpy/Scipy modulus function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The Numpy '**modulus**' function is used in a code to check if a certain time is an integral multiple of the time-step.

But some weird behavior is seeen.

- `numpy.mod(121e-12,1e-12)` returns 1e-12
- `numpy.mod(60e-12,1e-12)` returns '**a very small value**' (compared to 1e-12).

If you play around `numpy.mode('122-126'e-12,1e-12)` it gives randomly 0 and 1e-12.

Can someone please explain why?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, `np.mod(x1,x2)=x1-floor(x1/x2)*x2`. The problem here is that you are working with very small values, a dark domain where floating point errors (truncation...) happen quite often and results are often unpredictable...
I don't think you should spend a lot of time worrying about that.

Comment: These are interesting quirks that dont appear in Matlab or Octave. The Matlab/Octave modulus function is defined the same but behaves much better for much smaller values. Matlab probably scales the two numbers into a range where computational accuracy is no longer an issue.

Thanks.